# Make a scrollview automatically pull to one side if it is pulled halfway?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swipe, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a scrollview that has horizontal scrolling only. If it is moved to the right in a way that less than half of the current screen is moved to the left with the user's finger and then the user lets go, the scrollview automatically bounces back to where it was by moving to the right. If the scrollview is moved to the right in a way that more than half of the screen is moved to the right and then the user lets go, then the scrollview automatically bounces to the right. A lot of iOS applications have this (like Tinder), where if you swipe to the right partially, but not completely, then the original image that you were swiping to the right goes back to its original place. I have looked online extensively for a solution to this problem although I cannot find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true`. For more information, refer to [apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619432-ispagingenabled)